# Is it possible to read a file after receiving an event?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using a ActiveMQ Broker with built-in Camel Routes. I want to read a file after an Event received.

```
<pseudo>
 from Event A
 read File XY
 to Event B with Body from File XY
</pseuod>
```

I simple tried moving files from a temporary directory based on an event but only event B is written. In the Log file are no Exceptions or Error messages.

```xml
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <!-- You can use Spring XML syntax to define the routes here using the <route> element -->
        <route>
            <description>Example Camel Route</description>
            <from uri="activemq:example.A"/>
            <from uri="file://tmp/a?delete=true"/>
            <to uri="file://tmp/b?overruleFile=copy-of-${file:name}"/>
            <to uri="activemq:example.B"/>
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

**Update** with working solution for single file:

```xml
    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <!-- You can use Spring XML syntax to define the routes here using the <route> element -->
        <route>
            <description>Example Camel Route</description>
            <from uri="activemq:example.A"/>
            <pollEnrich>
               <constant>file:///tmp/a?fileName=file1</constant>
            </pollEnrich>
            <log message="file content  ${body}"/>
            <to uri="activemq:example.B"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Comment: Hi! You need to use a Poll Enrich EIP to allow you to use your second "from" as a file consumer. Look here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/pollEnrich-eip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Content Enrichers for this. [This](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-enricher.html#ContentEnricher-Example) is exactly what you are looking for.

```
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:example.A"/>
    <pollEnrich>
        <constant>file://tmp/a?delete=true</constant>
    </pollEnrich>
    <to uri="activemq:example.B"/>
</route>
```

Please be aware that for camel version 2.15 or older

> pollEnrich does not access any data from the current Exchange which
>   means when polling it cannot use any of the existing headers you may
>   have set on the Exchange. For example you cannot set a filename in the
>   Exchange.FILE_NAME header and use pollEnrich to consume only that
>   file. For that you must set the filename in the endpoint URI.

Comment: That is for Camel 2.15 or older

Comment: for future readers - don't forget the root / on unix file system `file:///tmp/a?fileName=dummy.txt`

Comment: @ClausIbsen sorry I missed to mention that. Thanks for pointing it out